# Python module name clash

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a module named after the product I'm working on, and some 3rd party built a package for our product's API with the same module name. In attempting to use the latter, the module names collide. If I change the name of the API package, I can't easily make changes and contribute back upstream. Changing our module name would be a mess.

This sounds like a crazy problem. Right now we're solving it by adding a "parent" module to the API module. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Using `import xx as yy` ? But by looking at your rep I'd say you already tried that.

Comment: Could you give us a usage scenario such as file structure? If you have your own application that imports both `product` the module and `product` the package, you could use relative importing to differentiate between the two.

Comment: They're in different directories, both in the python path. `import xx as yy` won't work, as whatever path comes first in the python path is the one that will be imported. @OozeMeister dir structure is: $ROOT/product and $ROOT/3rdparty/product where $ROOT and $ROOT/3rdparty are both in the python path.

Comment: Is the `3rdparty` directory the parent wrapper module you've added to it?

Comment: Really, I like adding a wrapper better than the black magic of modifying the path as it is clearly well-defined. As I've seen at my current job, modifying the path allows for some interesting problems on down the line and it makes it much harder to debug, not to mention it screws with any IDEs out there, so no auto-complete. Is there a reason you don't like the wrapper idea?

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your own modules in a package in this way:

1. create a dir (e.g. `mypylib`)
2. put an empty file named `__init__.py` in the dir
3. put your module implementation files (e.g. `mymod.py`) in the dir
4. assume there is a submodule named `submod` implemented in `mymod.py`

When you want to use `submod`, you should do this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "mypylib"))
from mypylib.mymod import submod
```

I think most 3rd-party modules apply similar rules to avoid from naming collision, and you should do this way, too.

In your current circumstance, you can simply put `__init__.py` and your modules in a package dir and then do string replacement on all your source file to apply the new arrangement of your modules.

I hope this helps.